# Durable corded USB mouse

Tags: mice

I'm looking to replace my current cheap-o usb mouse, as the buttons have started to go in earnest. I'd like to get a model that is durable, preferably with user-serviceable, mechanical switches. Of course, I could always just buy another 5-10$ model-- but it does feel wasteful to have to throw it away every couple of years. I'm not terribly fond of the "gaming" type of mouse, but, if it fits the bill, I'll consider it.

I'd also welcome a guide on repairing or replacing the switches in a mouse, although it seems like few people are interested in doing repairs on such cheap parts.

Comment: For what OS? [driver support can be important if not Windows]. Any 'button count' requirements? Did you checkout everything Logitech make? They've pretty much got the market covered at all price-points.

Comment: I use windows and linux both. In terms of buttons, I'm looking for the traditional 3-button type. Logitech seems to offer mostly cordless mice, and when I selected for my use case on their website (windows & linux, corded) they had only two options available-- a cheap-o 15 dollar mouse, and a slightly more expensive "advanced" corded mouse. Unfortunately, neither one mentions button life, my primary concern.

Comment: On the gaming side, logitech does offer more corded options. I could only find one that made any claim about button durability-- the "pro", which claims a 50 million click lifespan-- But, this seems like one of the best options I've found so far. for a "gaming" mouse, it is fairly reserved in it's design. I may go with this option, although the price feels a bit inflated, probably because of the super-crazy-overkill 25 000 dpi sensor...

Comment: "I'd also welcome a guide on repairing or replacing the switches in a mouse, although it seems like few people are interested in doing repairs on such cheap parts." is outta scope here but - pretty easy if you can get the switches. You pretty much can do it with some solder braid, flux, solder and a cheap soldering iron